# Sort by active and open

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

As of now, one may filter by no answer, needs answer, has bounty, hot today, and hot this week in the app. Can you add an "open" item, so that questions that are closed won't show in the list?

Comment: adding closed:no doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Catija Sure it does. I'm not talking about the search bar; I'm talking about the button below it with two arrows that says "active" and when you tap it you're given a bunch of other ways to sort the questions.